# Determining the sequence numbers of sent packets in TCP

Tags: tcp

I'm trying to learn TCP well from a textbook, and this is a problem that I am having trouble solving.

A sender using TCP Reno (with fast retransmit and fast recovery) is going to transmit 15 packets with the first sequence having sequence number 1. Assume the ACK numbers are the same as the corresponding packet numbers. Also, suppose that the congestion window starts at 6 and the first packet is lost (note that the connection has already been established, so the first packet doesn't refer to the packet used in the three-way handshake used to establish the connection).

If no other packets are lost during the transmission, what are the sequence numbers of the sent packets, acknowledgements, and the size of the congestion window at each step?

I'm really not too sure how to approach this problem, but I think that I need to figure out whether the packet lost was due to a timeout or three duplicate acknowledgements. However, I'm not even sure if I have enough information to do this.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: For a segment (not packet) that has the ACK flag set, the acknowledgement number is the next expected segment number, and it is acknowledging everything prior to the number.

Comment: Voting to close as homework

Answer (score 1):

As Ron mentioned in the comments, the reciever will send an ack for next packet it is expecting.
I think it would also be helpful to look at [TCP timers](https://tutorialspoint.dev/computer-science/computer-network-tutorials/computer-network-tcp-timers).

During TCP 3 way handshake, both client and server agree on window, that is based on multiple factors(congestion control, flow control, application throughput, etc)

When the client sends a set of segments.
It waits for an ack, for the next segment.
At the same time, it starts the TCP timer.

Lets take an example:
Client sends 10 segments from sequence number 1001-1010.
Lets say segment with sequence number 1003 was dropped by the network.

Server will send an ack for 1003 - the next segment it is expecting...

Now, at the end of the timer, if the client does not recieve an ack for segment 1011 so it knows that there has been packet loss in the network.

But how can client know if all the packets are lost or a certain segment is lost?

That is the reason why we use triple ack to denote missing packets:
Its explained very well [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30618/why-only-after-3-duplicate-ack-retransmission-takes-place-in-tcp).

This is also one of the reasons Reno can maintain high throughput in moderately congested networks.